# errors loading assetbundle in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'll start with the errors themselves. The first is : Assertion failed on expression: 'm_UncompressedBlocksOffsets[blockInd] <= from + dstPos && m_UncompressedBlocksOffsets[blockInd] + uncompressedBlockSize >= from + dstPos' UnityEngine.AssetBundle:LoadFromFile(String)

Followed by : Failed to decompress data for the AssetBundle 'D:/Unity/projects/PQv0.10/Assets/AssetBundles/spritesbundle'. UnityEngine.AssetBundle:LoadFromFile(String)

I've always just used the resources folder for my projects but my current project has outgrown what that method can accommodate. So I'm trying to offload assets (in this case 5000 or so sprites)into an assetbundle and load them as needed at runtime. I figured I could just get a reference to the assetbundle and then call assetbundle.LoadAsset(assetname), substituting my old Resources.Load calls. Here's my attempt at making the assetbundle reference that keeps erroring:

```
AssetBundle sprites;
void loadSprites()
{
    sprites = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/spritesbundle");                //          " + bundleName);
    if (!sprites) {
        Debug.Log("failed to load assetbundle");
    }
}
```

For due diligence, here's also the code I used to create that assetbundle. It simple searches my project for png's and packs them into the assetbundle:

```
public static void SaveSpecificAssets()
{
    AssetBundleBuild build = new AssetBundleBuild();
    build.assetBundleName = "spritesBundle";

    string[] files = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();
    List<string> validFiles = new List<string>();
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        if (file.EndsWith(".png")) validFiles.Add(file);
    }

    build.assetNames = validFiles.ToArray();

    BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles", new AssetBundleBuild[1] { build }, BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
}
```

The assetbundle builds without errors and appears in the directory where it should be. I have no indication that it's faulty other than the errors I get when trying to load it. The manifest it generates contains appropriate items so I think it's working as intended at least.If I'm missing any relevant information, please point it out and I'll try to provide it.

this is the test coroutine I used in place of loadSprites() for testing if it made a difference:

```
IEnumerator testLoader()
{
    WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload("file:///" + Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/spritesbundle", 1);
    yield return www;

    sprites = www.assetBundle;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for all the PNG's in your project folder, select them all and add them to an AssetBundle via the Editor, Then just build using

```
BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles("Assets/AssetBundles",BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows);
```

Then try to load the bundles and see if it shows an error.

Also, look into the **Manifest** to see if all the files you intended are listed

Comment: The manifest looks appropriate. The directories for files all appear to show up where they should be.

Comment: I know it's deprecated but try loading the asset bundle using the WWW class in unity.

Comment: I wrote a quick test coroutine, after a few seconds it errors out with this message: "You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
Failed to decompress data for the AssetBundle 'file:///D:/Unity/projects/PQv0.10/Assets/AssetBundles/spritesbundle'. URL: file:///D:/Unity/projects/PQv0.10/Assets/AssetBundles/spritesbundle
UnityEngine.WWW:get_assetBundle()"

Comment: Hmmm ... Reports suggest it can be due to a bad unity patch. Which version of unity are you using? If old, upgrade to the latest one, before that did you try out the method suggested in the answer? Assigning assetbundles via the editor and not via code?

Comment: I had been using a version a few patches old, so I updated to the latest patch today in hopes of a resolution.

Comment: Also, check if all the PNG import settings is set to Sprite or UI 2D

Comment: Doing it by hand is really slow but I'm working on it. In one folder alone I have over 4000 sprites and it often crashes unity when I select them all. Just selecting things takes a long time for some reason and about 15g memory.

Comment: From this link https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/DownloadingAssetBundles.html
The size of the cache is 4gb max. Does your asset bundle exceed 4 gigs when compressed? If so try the www.object method described in the same link. Or try to package only a couple of sprites in your bundle and try loading it. Sources confirm that the cause is the actual building of asset bundles

Comment: If the bundle loads with less number of PNG's then compression might be the issue. you will have to create separate bundles of viable sizes instead of one large bundle.

Comment: 4400 of those sprites are contained in a folder outside of unity only taking up 115 MB, so I have no clue how unity would manage to force them to use so much space. Still working on manual build btw, Unity crashed on me.

Comment: Yeah try with a substantially lesser amount of sprites this time

Comment: OK, I've tried it now with only a single sprite and I've been able to load and get a reference to the assetbundle in a runtime script with the coroutine utilising WWW. For some reason trying to use AssetBundle.LoadFromFile is still erroring out.